# Showing $\displaystyle \lim_{(t_1,t_2) \to (t,t), t_1 < t_2} \frac{\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}=\gamma'(t)$ ( using uniform continuity )

Tags: analysis, riemannian-geometry, uniform-continuity

I am reading the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifold, p.266~ 271, proof of Theorem 9.1 ( Rotation Index theorem ) and trying to understand some statement.

Let $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a positively oriented curved polygon ( by definition, refer to John lee's book p.265 ). In fifth paragraph of the proof, he argues as follows :

Let $ a \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq b$. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus gives

$$\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)  = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{ds}\gamma(t_1 + s(t_2 - t_1))ds=\int_{0}^{1}\gamma'(t_1+s(t_2-t_1))(t_2-t_1)ds.$$

And thus

$$ \left|\frac{\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} -\gamma'(t) \right|\le \int_{0}^{1}|\gamma'(t_1+s(t_2-t_1))-\gamma'(t) | ds.$$

Because $\gamma'$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[a,b]$, this last expression can be made as small as desired by taking $(t_1, t_2)$ close to $(t,t)$. It follows that

$$\lim_{(t_1,t_2) \to (t,t), t_1 < t_2} \frac{\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}=\gamma'(t). $$

And why this is true? How can we use the uniform continuity of $\gamma'$?  Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to uniformly continuous, we know that $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exist a $\delta>0$ such that $\forall \tau_{1},\tau_{2}$, if $|\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}|\leq\delta$, then we have $|\gamma'(\tau_{1})-\gamma'(\tau_{2})|\leq\epsilon$.

In your question, when $t_{1},t_{2}$ close enough, that is to say, $|t_{1}+s(t_{2}-t_{1})-t|\leq\delta$, so we have$|\gamma'(t_{1}+s(t_{2}-t_{1}))-\gamma'(t)|\leq\epsilon$, you integral domain about $t$ is $[0,1]$ finite, so we finish the argument!

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask further? You mean, if $|t_1 + s(t_2 -t_1) -t | < \delta$ , then $\int_{0}^{1}|\gamma'(t_1+s(t_2-t_1))-\gamma'(t) | ds < \int_{0}^{1} \epsilon ds = \epsilon$ ?
     My question is, why the sentence "$t_1, t_2$ close enough" implies $|t_1 + s(t_2 -t_1) -t | < \delta$ ?
      Uhm..what is the definition of $\lim_{(t_1,t_2) \to (t,t), t_1 < t_2} \frac{\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$? Perhaps, can you explain more friendly?

Comment: Ok, if $t_{1},t_{1}$ close enough, then $|t_{1}-t_{2}|<\delta$. Because $t$ and $t_{1}+s(t_{2}-t_{1})$ are two points in the interval $[t_{1},t_{2}]$, naturally, we know that$ |t_{1}+s(t_{2}−t_{1})−t|<δ$

Comment: Thanks! Why $t \in [t_1, t_2]$ ? By assumption ( taking  $(t_1, t_2)$ close to $(t,t)$ ) ? P.s. I am still not understand the defitinion of  $\lim_{(t_1,t_2) \to (t,t), t_1 < t_2} \frac{\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I'm wrong, $t\notin [t_{1},t_{2}]$. But when $t_{1}\to t,t_{2}\to t$, we can also get the conclusion. The definition of that limit is "For $\forall\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that when $|t_{1}-t|<\delta,|t_{2}-t|<\delta$, we have $|\frac{\gamma(t_{2})-\gamma(t_{1})}{t_{2}-t_{1}}-I|<\epsilon$", where $I$ is the limit value. Of course, you can use the definition of Cauchy.

Comment: O.K. Fix $\epsilon >0$. Then by the uniform continuity, there exists $\delta_0 >0$ such that for all $\tau_1, \tau_2$, if $| \tau_1-\tau_2| < \delta_0 $, then $|\gamma'(\tau_1)-\gamma'(\tau_2)| < \epsilon$.
      
      Then, my question is, does there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that "if $|t_1 -t | <\delta_1 , |t_2 - t_1| < \delta_1$, then $ |t_1 + s(t_2-t_1) -t  | < \delta_0$  ( $0 \le s \le 1$ ) "? If this is true, then as argued in my first comment, we are done. And..is that true?

Comment: Of course it is right, we can let $|t-t_{1}|\leq\delta_{1}\leq\frac{\delta_{0}}{3}$,$|t-t_{1}|\leq\delta_{1}\leq\frac{\delta_{0}}{3}$, so $|t_{1}+s(t_{2}-t_{1})-t|\leq |t_{1}-t|+|t_{2}-t|\leq \frac{2\delta_{0}}{3}$

Comment: Thank you. More correctly, my guess is that,
        $ | t_1 + s(t_2 - t_1) -t | \le |t_1 -t| + |s(t_2 - t_1)| \le |t_1 -t| + | t_2 - t_1 | 
         = |t_1 -t | + | t_2 -t + t -t_1| \le |t_1 -t| + | t_2-t| + | t_1-t| < \frac{\delta_0}{3} + \frac{\delta_0}{3} + \frac{\delta_0}{3} = \delta_0 .$  True?

Comment: Yeah, you are right! you are very serious and careful and have a very strict attitude to the details of calculation, good, best wishes!

Comment: Thank you ! :) ~